# Generate random bytes Cocoa?

Tags: cocoa, encryption, byte, initialization-vector

I need to generate some random data to append to my file for encryption. How would I go about doing this? Would it be sort of the same idea as generating a string of random characters?

Something like:

```
NSData *randomData = @"what should i put here?";
```

And then use the rand() function to randomize the data?

Your help is greatly appreciated

Comment: How will you know what bytes are the random addition and which are part of the original plaintext when you decrypt?  There are already a number of different cryptographic padding schemes for use in different circumstances, most of which are easier to chop off afterwards than a bunch of random bytes.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[`int SecRandomCopyBytes (
   SecRandomRef rnd,
   size_t count,
   uint8_t *bytes
);`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Security/Reference/RandomizationReference/Reference/reference.html)

For example:

```
uint8_t data[100];
int err = 0;

// Don't ask for too many bytes in one go, that can lock up your system
err = SecRandomCopyBytes(kSecRandomDefault, 100, data);
if(err != noErr)
    @throw [NSException exceptionWithName:@"..." reason:@"..." userInfo:nil];

NSData* randomData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:data length:100];
```

As noted by Peter in the comments, you can also do this:

```
NSMutableData* data = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:100];
err = SecRandomCopyBytes(kSecRandomDefault, 100, [data mutableBytes]);
```

And as noted by Rob in the comments, you need to link Security.framework for SecRandomCopyBytes to be available. You also need to include `SecRandom.h`.

Comment: Yes; you can use [NSData initWithBytes: length:] to get to the data into an NSData object.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific?

Comment: You could save some work by creating an NSMutableData object of the desired length and passing its `mutableBytes` pointer as the buffer for `SecRandomCopyBytes` to write into.

Comment: @PeterHosey Agreed. See http://robnapier.net/blog/aes-commoncrypto-564 for an example of this. Search for `randomDataOfLength:`. This is a very convenient way to manage buffers.

Comment: I believe you need to link Security.framework to get `SecRandomCopyBytes()`. That may be what's causing the trouble for the OP.

Comment: @RobNapier: One avenue of improvement there: You can use the `strerror` function to get a description of the `errno` value.

Answer (score 1):

On UNIX you can rely on /dev/random or /dev/urandom to obtain randomness of cryptographic quality.

```
NSData *bytes = [[NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath: @"/dev/random"] readDataOfLength: 100];
```

As it seems, it reads 100 bytes from /dev/random. Refer to `man urandom` for details.

Comment: Note this is very easy but it fails if your app is in the App Sandbox, where it can't get at /dev

Comment: /dev/random is accessible from an unplugged iOS device. Is it sandboxed on macOS?